# How to create a score function in scikit learn such that it considers other auxiliary variables?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Say I have a data set with categorical features `X, Y` and labels `Z`. And suppose it is a binary classification problem. Now I want to create a custom scorer, that will compute the f1 score with respect to `Z` and `Z_estimated`, for `X == 0` and `X == 1` differently and take their weighted average. How do I do that? I haven't seen any example in scikit-learn documentation that creates a custom scorer like this.